# Count Occurrences of words with Case sensitives

Tags: java, arrays, underscore-java

How can we find the occurrences of words in an array of Strings with Case sensitive

e.g. [AA, Bb, Aa, aa, BB]  ===> {AA=3, Bb=2}

```
[AAa,aaa,BBB,bbb,BbB,AaA,AAc]  ===> {AAa=3, BBB=3 , AAc=1}
```

The count should be against the first appearance of the word

ConcurrentHashMap<String,Integer> hm = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
String[] s1 = {"AA", "Bb", "Aa", "aa", "BB"};

```
    for (String s:s1) {
        if (hm.size()==0)
            hm.put(s,1);
        else {
            Set<String> keySet = hm.keySet();
            for (String s2 : keySet) {
                if (s2.equalsIgnoreCase(s)) {
                    Integer val = hm.get(s2);
                    hm.put(s2, ++val);
                    break;
                } else {
                    hm.put(s, 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(hm);
```

Comment: Your problem is that `hm.put(s,1);` is inside the inner `for` loop, but it needs to be outside.  You'd find it much simpler if you used either the lower case version of every string, or the upper case version, as the map key.  If you do that, you won't need the inner loop at all.

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question. Does your code not work? If your code doesn't work, how does it fail? What are the expected results? What are the actual results?  Where do you think the problem lies?

Comment: Off Topic: Is your program multi-threaded? Is concurrency an issue? If not, you could try a `HashMap`

Comment: I have tried the above code but the output is not as required ..
{AA=3, Bb=2, BB=1} instead of {AA=3, Bb=2}

With hm.put(s,1) on the outer loop also not working

Comment: It's moot now that there is a good answer. But, for future reference, a good question might show an example with input, actual output, and expected output, possibly with an explanation of why the actual output is not as required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap-java.util.Comparator-) allows you to provide a custom key comparator. One such comparator is [`String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER).

```
final TreeMap<String, Integer> treeMap
        = new TreeMap<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
final String[] s1 = {"AA", "Bb", "Aa", "aa", "BB"};

for (final String s : s1) {
    treeMap.merge(s, 1, Integer::sum);
}

System.out.println(treeMap);
```

Output:

```
{AA=3, Bb=2}
```

I know, boring. Where's the fun in that? :)